# How to save multiple dataframes into multiple worksheets in xlsx

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsx

I have 3 dataframes. Two of them I want to save in one worksheet, third I want to save in another worksheet. In the end, 2 worksheets should be in one xlsx file. How can I do that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [creating multiple excel worksheets using data in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981820/creating-multiple-excel-worksheets-using-data-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: I don't know how to combine these 2 things: 2 dataframes in one worksheet and 2 worksheets in one xlsx file. I found solutions to these problems one at a time, but they were so different (different methods) that I have no way of combining them.

Comment: When you want 2 dataframes in one worksheet, do these 2 dataframes have same column names ?

Comment: No, they have other names

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if it's what you needed

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with 3 dataframes at beginning. Then I concatenate the dataframes `df2` and `df3` into `df_concat`. Finally I save `df1` in first worksheet, and `df_concat` in second worksheet :

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2], 'col2': [3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [11,22], 'B': [33,44]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'C': [55,66], 'D': [77,88], 'E': [99,100]})

df_concat = pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=1)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('my_multiple_worksheets_excel.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_a')
df_concat.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_b')

writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it not solved my problem. 2 dataframes cant be concatenating, 
because they have a different number and column names

Comment: I edited my answer with `axis=1` in the concatenation and some modifications in dataframes. Check if this is good now :)

Comment: No :( There are 2 independet tables. I just want to put it in worksheet with 2 of headers with column names.