# How do I import my data into a table in an xlsx file using Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am pretty new to Pandas and was wondering if there was a way that would let me take the data I want and put it in an xlsx file as a table.

This is what I have so far for my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#defining the excel file and the sheet(s) and printing them
excel_file_1 = 'Incident Report.xls' 
df_first_shift = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\M\Downloads\Incident Report.xls') 
print(df_first_shift) 

#combining all the data from the sheets into one file
df_all = pd.concat([df_first_shift]) 

#Creating the .xlsx file 
df_all.to_excel(r'C:\Users\M\OneDrive\Test\Incident_Report.xlsx') 

#Deleting a row
wb = load_workbook(r'C:\Users\M\OneDrive\Test\Incident_Report.xlsx') 
ws = wb['Sheet1']  
ws.delete_cols(1) 
wb.save(r'C:\Users\M\OneDrive\Test\Incident_Report.xlsx')
```

Comment: See the docs for openpyxl https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=table&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Comment: Which error are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new excel every time from a dataframe, pandas has a [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) function which you should use. If you want to write multiple data frames to an excel this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981820/creating-multiple-excel-worksheets-using-data-in-a-pandas-dataframe) is helpful.