# Can't export multiple DataFrames to different sheets in Excel using XlsxWriter

Tags: python, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I am using `XlsxWriter`, and trying to export 2 `DF`s to 2 different Sheets in `Excel`. I followed this [`link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981820/creating-multiple-excel-worksheets-using-data-in-a-pandas-dataframe). But it doesn't work for me. Let me illustrate:

```
# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[7,8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'C':['AA','BB','CC']})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(path,'Output.xlsx'), engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
writer.save()
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2', index=False)
writer.save()
```

In `Output.xlsx` I can only see Sheet1 corresponding to `df1`, but not Sheet2.

**Output**:

[image]

But, if I would have used engine as `openpyxl` instead of `xlsxwriter`, I can see both the `dfs` exported into Sheet1 & Sheet2.

I think, there is a small tweak, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Remove `writer.save`. You're saving to the same file 4 times. Twice from Pandas and twice from the writer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `writer.save()`. Calling `to_excel` has already saved the data.

The [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) docs explain you only need to use a different sheet name to save to different sheets.

> Multiple sheets may be written to by specifying unique sheet_name.

This is shown in the doc examples too:

```
df2 = df1.copy()
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
```