# How to iterate through for loop and write each dataframe to different excel sheets

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm looping through list of jsons and storing them in a dataframe. for each iteration i want to write the dataframe into excel with different sheets. how to achieve this?

```
for item in data:

  #removing empty columns in raw data
  drop_none = lambda path, key, value: key is not None and value is not None
  cleaned = remap(item, visit=drop_none)
  new_data=flatten(cleaned)
  #my_df = new_data.dropna(axis='columns', how='all') # Drops columns with all NA values
  dfFromRDD2 = spark.createDataFrame(new_data)
```

I want to save the dataframe dfFromRDD2 to excel with different sheets on each iterations.
is their a way to do it using python?

Comment: you can use pandas to create a df from `new_data` and use `df.to_excel()`

Comment: i mean like even sheets name should be dynamic, how to do that?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21981820/8279585) will help